# SSRS and large data set

Tags: ssrs-2016

I am trying to automate a data dump in SSRS but since the data set is large, I receive the out of memory error message. yes, SSRS is not designed for data dump report but this report is being requested frequently and I am trying to get it off my plate by automating it. Any thoughts/suggestions?

T‌hank You,

H‌elal‌‌

Comment: Find the data source behind it and run that directly in SSMS. _or_ understand why users are asking for data dumps - can you improve the report so they don't need these?

Comment: Any reason this data dump request can't be processed via SSIS and retain the original report as is for ad-hoc report purpose? I take it when you say data dump, you are referring to data-driven subscriptions. Is it not?

Comment: Nick, I am not sure about your questions. I know my data source and I am running the query directly in SSMS. The user is sort of power user and has template with pivot tables. So when I send him the raw data, he paste it in his template and he is done. The issue is almost every week I have to refresh this data dump for him. Of course, alternative to SSRS is to create a stored procedure and schedule it to run every Monday morning.

Comment: VKarthik, I never thought of SSIS...that might be a good option or as I just indicated to Nick perhaps a stored procedure should take care of it. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: How about you create a stored procedure / view that the end user can consume via Excel for example. Offering data dumps via SSRS is not idea and is time consuming not to mention inefficient.